# Fail CloudFormation stack if EC2 cfn-init fails

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I use CloudFormation to provision EC2 instances (via ASG and LaunchTemplate),

Is it possible to Fail CloudFormation stack if EC2 cfn-init command fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failure of cfn-init will cause the stack to fail, however the time out can be quite long.

Use

```
CreationPolicy:
  ResourceSignal:
    Timeout: PT15M
```

in your `Resource`. Adjust the `Timeout` as you require.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [cfn-signal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjB3MW7iZvhAhWUfisKHULKBUUQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2FAWSCloudFormation%2Flatest%2FUserGuide%2Fcfn-signal.html&usg=AOvVaw2a9mLklQGIaKDcxWun4gSu) to send out SUCCESS/FAILED signals

You can check [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/community/services/VPC/vpc_template.json) example where they use cfn-signal along with cfn-init and function error_exit will send failure signal if execution was failed.